# Eclipse CSS AutoComplete/Content Assist not working

Tags: css, eclipse, autocomplete, ide, content-assist

Hi I am running Eclipse 4.3.2 Kepler. My CSS content assist is not working at all. I press ctrl+space to no avail.

I looked at my content assist settings and it is checked as well as having both CSS Proposals and CSS Template proposal checked.

What is going on?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the CSS editor for the file? For example do you get syntax coloring?

Comment: Yes, I get all the CSS syntax coloring. I'm trying a few things at the moment. Still no solution.

Comment: is the css editor installed by default? whats its name? cant find it in my luna eclipse version

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem ? It works for me only when I remove the CSS link in the header... strange....Any idea ?  <link rel="stylesheet"
 href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

Answer (score 1):

This could also be due to the css file location. If you are using maven and have the css in location like \src\main\resources\css\bootstrap.css, it does not work.

Instead if the css file is placed directly under webapp it works.